# How to save data to model coredata

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, core-data

I want to save my data to core data when a button is clicked here is my action button code now `let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = app.managedObjectContext
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Cart", inManagedObjectContext: context)
            let cart = Cart(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)` but the only problem now is that i dont how to save here is my code to parse json

```
      Alamofire.request(.GET, url!, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        let result = response.result

        if response.result.isSuccess{
            let jsonObj = JSON(result.value!)
            if let x = jsonObj["Items"].array {
                x.forEach
                    {
                        if let uw = ($0["name"]).string{
                            print(uw)
                            let qw = ($0["image"]).string
                            if let rw = ($0["price"]).int{
                                if let hu = ($0["id"]).int{
                                print(hu)
                                let foo = Rest(name: uw, imageUrl: qw!, price: "₦\(rw)")
                                    self.rest.append(foo)

                                }


                            }

                        }

                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    actInd.stopAnimating()

                }

            }

        }
```

So i have an array called rest which is where i want get data for the tableview. I want to save information of each cell tapped into coredata here is a screenshot of the app[image: Screenshot]

So when the sure button is tapped it saves the item to coredata
here is my code incase you nee[code](http://pastebin.com/Nf8aKhvn)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, adapted to your code.

In the portion that you have (...let app=...) replace it by this:

```
 let app2 = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! UIApplicationDelegate
        if let context2 = app2.managedObjectContext {
            let cart2 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Cart", inManagedObjectContext: context2) as! Cart
            cart2.name = self.res.name
            cart2.price = self.res.price
            cart2.url = self.res.imageUrl
            cart2.id = ""
            // Perform a save operation
            do {
                try context2?.save()
            } catch {
                let saveError = error as NSError
                print(saveError)
            }
      }
```

Let me know if this works.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just an example here when you want to save your data in coredata. You have to create entity/model and all the setup for core data elements. For details please study https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

```
  func saveName(name: String) {
  //1
  let appDelegate =
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

  let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

  //2
  let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person",
    inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

  let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
    insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

  //3
  person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")

  //4
  do {
    try managedContext.save()
  //5
    people.append(person)
  } catch let error as NSError  {
      print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }
}
```

Comment: So i will call the function in my parseJson() function?

Comment: "I want to save information of each cell tapped into coredata here is a screenshot of the app". So when cell tapped tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath method will be called.which imformation you want to save now? cart object ?

Comment: I want to save name and price did u see my code? how can i save it from there